# Silverlight assembly dynamic loading and unloading

Tags: silverlight, assemblies, dynamically-loaded-xap

Does silverlight provide a mechanism like full .NET framework's AppDomain for loading and unloading of assemblies?
How can I unload an unused assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to unload assemblies in Silverlight (short of tearing down the entire app and recreating it, such as by reseting the "source" property of the object tag in HTML).

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks for confirming.